# What is the practical difference between krb5-self and krb5-subdomain in BIND9 update-policy statement?

Tags: bind, kerberos, dynamic-dns

What is the practical difference between krb5-self and krb5-subdomain policies in BIND9 on update-policy statement while dealing with dynamic DNS updates on zones?

From the BIND9 documentation it states the following:

> krb5-self: This rule takes a Kerberos machine principal
> (host/QDN@REALM) and allows it to update the DNS entry which
> corresponds to the QDN part of the Principal. The REALM to be matched
> must exactly match that specified in identity. See Kerberos/AD note.
>
> krb5-subdomain: This rule takes a Kerberos machine principal (host/QDN@REALM) and allows it to update the QDN part of the
> Principal. The REALM to be matched must match that specified in
> identity or any subdomain (labels to the left) of identity. See
> Kerberos/AD note.

But this is extremely vague, and there's even a CVE saying that krb5-subdomain does not do what is does and there's a new player in the game: krb5-selfsub: https://kb.isc.org/docs/cve-2018-5741